# How to correct smooth moving the marker in google maps v2?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, gps, google-maps-markers

In my application based on one from https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples needs to display a smooth "move" google maps marker from one point to another.
I use the following method for the animation:

```
public void animateMarker(final Marker marker, final LatLng toPosition,
                          final boolean hideMarker) {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    Projection proj = mMap.getProjection();
    Point startPoint = proj.toScreenLocation(marker.getPosition());
    final LatLng startLatLng = proj.fromScreenLocation(startPoint);
    final long duration = 500;

    final Interpolator interpolator = new LinearInterpolator();

    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            long elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
            float t = interpolator.getInterpolation((float) elapsed
                    / duration);
            double lng = t * toPosition.longitude + (1 - t)
                    * startLatLng.longitude;
            double lat = t * toPosition.latitude + (1 - t)
                    * startLatLng.latitude;
            marker.setPosition(new LatLng(lat, lng));

            if (t < 1.0) {
                // Post again 16ms later.
                handler.postDelayed(this, 16);
            } else {
                if (hideMarker) {
                    marker.setVisible(false);
                } else {
                    marker.setVisible(true);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

But as a result of simply creating a new marker to the new location (though old is not removed):

[image]

Comment: I think you need to tell the view to redraw itself after you change one position, and before you start waiting.

Comment: Did you mean a delete marker and add new one with new position?

Comment: As far as my understand, in order to save resources, Android does not draw the screen until your loop finish... so you need to tell the system that you want to redraw the screen. Seems like this would help: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate(android.graphics.Rect)

Comment: I tried to reproduce and I fail.. mine is working fine: https://youtu.be/s_gZR1WHqPw

Comment: can you post a code, please?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I copied some of the code from the [project](https://gist.github.com/broady/6314689) mentioned in the [official video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WKfZsCKSXVQ).

I tried to reproduce it with this code and this [seems to be working for me](https://youtu.be/s_gZR1WHqPw), so hopefully my code would help you, even for a bit.

```
static final LatLng SomePos = new LatLng(37.7796354, -122.4159606);

    try {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        }
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        googleMap.setTrafficEnabled(false);
        googleMap.setIndoorEnabled(false);
        googleMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(SomePos));
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(googleMap.getCameraPosition().target)
                .zoom(17)
                .bearing(30)
                .tilt(45)
                .build()));

        myMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(SomePos)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                .title("Hello world"));


        googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {

                final LatLng startPosition = myMarker.getPosition();
                final LatLng finalPosition = new LatLng(37.7801569,-122.4148528);
                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                final Interpolator interpolator = new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator();
                final float durationInMs = 3000;
                final boolean hideMarker = false;

                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    long elapsed;
                    float t;
                    float v;

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // Calculate progress using interpolator
                        elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
                        t = elapsed / durationInMs;
                        v = interpolator.getInterpolation(t);

                        LatLng currentPosition = new LatLng(
                                startPosition.latitude*(1-t)+finalPosition.latitude*t,
                                startPosition.longitude*(1-t)+finalPosition.longitude*t);

                        myMarker.setPosition(currentPosition);

                        // Repeat till progress is complete.
                        if (t < 1) {
                            // Post again 16ms later.
                            handler.postDelayed(this, 16);
                        } else {
                            if (hideMarker) {
                                myMarker.setVisible(false);
                            } else {
                                myMarker.setVisible(true);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

                return true;

            }

        });

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

I know this is an old question but...

You can use value interpolator for this task :

```
fun changePositionSmoothly(marker:Marker?, newLatLng: LatLng){
    if(marker == null){
        return;
    }
    val animation = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0f, 100f)
    var previousStep = 0f
    val deltaLatitude = newLatLng.latitude - marker.position.latitude
    val deltaLongitude = newLatLng.longitude - marker.position.longitude
    animation.setDuration(1500)
    animation.addUpdateListener { updatedAnimation ->
        val deltaStep = updatedAnimation.getAnimatedValue() as Float - previousStep
        previousStep = updatedAnimation.getAnimatedValue() as Float
        marker.position = LatLng(marker.position.latitude + deltaLatitude * deltaStep * 1/100, marker.position.longitude + deltaStep * deltaLongitude * 1/100)
    }
    animation.start()
}
```

In Java

```
void changePositionSmoothly(Marker marker, LatLng newLatLng) {
        if (marker == null) {
            return;
        }
        ValueAnimator animation = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0f, 100f);
        final float[] previousStep = {0f};
        double deltaLatitude = newLatLng.latitude - marker.getPosition().latitude;
        double deltaLongitude = newLatLng.longitude - marker.getPosition().longitude;
        animation.setDuration(1500);
        animation.addUpdateListener(animation1 -> {
            float deltaStep = (Float) animation1.getAnimatedValue() - previousStep[0];
            previousStep[0] = (Float) animation1.getAnimatedValue();
            marker.setPosition(new LatLng(marker.getPosition().latitude + deltaLatitude * deltaStep * 1 / 100, marker.getPosition().longitude + deltaStep * deltaLongitude * 1 / 100));
        });
        animation.start();
    }
```

To prevent error accumulation, at the end of the animation you can set the new position, but this is enough for most cases.